# Задача: найти максимальный простой делитель числа 600851475143

Tags: javascript

помогите плз. написал вот такой код. не работает. 
как вариант пробовал сперва добавить найденные простые числа в массив и извлечь последнее.

```
function prime() {
    var primeDiv = 1;    
    for (var i = 2; i < 600851475143 ; i++) {
        if ( 600851475143 % i == 0 ) {
            primeDiv = i;
        } 
        return primeDiv;  
    };    
};

console.log( prime() );
```

Этот код дает результат "1" правильный ответ - 6857.
Ответов на разных языках масса, но что конкретно с этим кодом не так?

Comment: А что не работает? Судя по коду, что вы от него хотели, то правильно работает. Массив вы никакой не заполняете. Возвращаете значения изнутри цикла.... В общем это странно было бы если бы работало

Comment: Чтобы понять, в чём проблема, опишите реализуемый алгоритм словами, пошагово.

Comment: Код не дает результата.
Почему, не понимаю. На самом деле, в задаче автор зря сделал такое большое число. в случае ошибки браузер подвисает на раз, а с использованием меньшего числа правильного ответа (который вводится в форму) не получить

Comment: @Nuby, добавьте в вопрос информацию: что вы получаете, что хотели получать, как _по вашему_ должен работать приведенный алгоритм?

Comment: это код дает результат "1"
правильный ответ - 6857

ответов на разных языках масса, но что конкретно с этим котом не так?

Comment: @Nuby Конкретно с этим кодом, не так то, что `return primeDiv;` стоит внутри цикла, вынесите `return primeDiv;` за первую `};`

Comment: жесть какая )) 
вчера после неудачного запуска большое число подвесило браузер и вышибло live reload.
само собой, пробовал переместить return за скобки но уже ничего не работало. 

спасибо большое.

ps а вообще здесь тусовка всегда так бурно реагирует на то, что можно ответить одним коротким предложением? ...

Comment: кстате о максимальном, а не 600851475067 максимально простое, приближенное к вашему?

Comment: @Nuby всё зависит от того как поставлен вопрос) Ведь вся "тусовка" ждала когда будет "Ответов на разных языках масса, но что конкретно с этим кодом не так?"

Comment: _"правильный ответ - 6857"_ - нет, неправильный.

Comment: @Grundy, ты уверен, что правильно вопрос исправил? Возможно что из числа  надо было выбрать подстроку? Что за 6857?

Comment: @Qwertiy, я просто комментарий перенес

Comment: @Grundy, я про правку заголовка: "из" -> "которое меньше".

Comment: @Qwertiy, так-то это не моя правка была :)

Comment: Система приняла правильный ответ как 6857 
"

The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?"
тут уж ничего не поделать. 

а как по-настоящему правильно?

Comment: @Nuby, это просто задача переведена не правильно :) нужно найти максимальный простой **делитель**. А не просто какое-то простое число

Comment: Понятно. То-то я сразу не понял, что такое "prime factor". Бегло посмотрел перевод, а там как-то не очень и переведено.

Comment: @Grundy, ой :)​

Answer (score 1):

Возможно это поможет (поиск наибольшего простого числа не больше заданного)?

```
<script>
/*
Перебираем все цифры (N), которые оканчиваются на 1, 3, 7 или 9
(всё, что кончается на 0 или 5, явно не простое число ),
и делим их на все числа от 3 до корня от N включительно.
*/
  function PrimeFactors(n)
  {
    if (n<=2 || n==5)
      return n;
    for (var i = n; i >= 2; --i)
    {
      if (i==2 || i==5) return i;
      var i10 = i%10;
      if (i10 == 1 || i10 == 3 || i10 == 7 || i10 == 9)
      {
        var maxJ = Math.sqrt(i);
        var easy = true;
        for (var j=3; j<=maxJ; ++j)
        {
          easy = i%j != 0;
          if (!easy) break;
        }
        if (easy) return i;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }
  document.write(PrimeFactors(600851475143 ));
</script>
```

взял за основу [эту статью](http://denisx.ru/tech/prime-number/)

PS: Поиск максимального простого делителя (алгоритм не оптимизировал поэтому ждать надо 10-20 секунд):

```
<script>
function SearchMaxPrimeDelitel(n)
{
  n = Math.abs(n);
  for (var d=1; d<n/2; ++d) 
    if (n%d == 0)
    {
      var i = n/d;
      if (i==5 || i==2)
        return i;
      var i10 = i%10;
      if (i10 == 1 || i10 == 3 || i10 == 7 || i10 == 9)
      {
        var easy = true;
        var maxJ = Math.sqrt(i);
        for (var j=3; j<=maxJ; ++j)
        {
          easy = i%j != 0;
          if (!easy) break;
        }
        if (easy) return i;
      }
    }
  return 1;
}
document.write(SearchMaxPrimeDelitel(600851475143 ));
</script>
```

Comment: 5 - простое число

Comment: Grundy да! спасибо исправил. Просто к данной задачи это пофиг. Ну уж раз пошла такая пляска...

Answer (score 0):

зачем перебирать все значения i?
достаточно найти первый наименьший, который по логике составляет пару для наибольшего. Т.е. например, наименьший делитель для 1000 - это 2. А наибольший - 500. Если же 2х500 = 1000, следовательно 500 будет наибольшим делителем
на Go я бы написал как-то так:

```
import (
    "fmt"
)
func main() {
    count := 600851475143
    maxDivide := 0
    for i := 2; maxDivide == 0; i ++ {
        if count % i == 0 {
            maxDivide = count / i
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(maxDivide)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот решение на питоне. А вообще, задачки из Project Euler лучше решать самому. Иначе зачем их вообще решать?

```
def PrimeFactors(n):
    divisor = 2
    l = []
    while divisor ** 2 <= n:
        if n % divisor == 0:
            n //= divisor
            l.append(divisor)
        else:
            divisor += 1
    if n != 1:
        l.append(n)
    return l

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(max(PrimeFactors(600851475143)))
```

Comment: Это javascript? Автор указал язык программирования в теге. Если нужен алгоритм - указывается тег `алгоритм`. Да и почему из `Project Euler`? Вы думаете, что это единственный проект с такими задачами? Да их тьма-тьмущая. А в зависимости от языка программирования на подобных проектах даются и интервалы чисел для вычислений и время работы проверочного теста, т.е. для Си код должен будет, например, выполняться не более 5 секунд, а для javascript или php может ограничение быть в минуту.

Comment: И по поводу упрека автору, что лучше решать самому... Так он это и пытается сделать. Он и предоставил свою попытку, а не чужой код. И просит помощи. А вот Вы именно, написав про то, что лучше решать самому, оказываете медвежью услугу автору, подсовывая готовое решение, а не помогая разобраться. И, тем самым, противоречите сами себе.

Comment: Project Euler потому что google:What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143? Таких задач тьма-тьмущая, но 600851475143 встречается далеко не часто. Я привел алгоритм, который выпоняется на скриптовом языке за 0m0.036s. И вряд-ли составит труд перенести код с языка Python на JavaScript - структура очевидна.

Comment: А Вы знаете способности автора? Может он вчера только открыл учебник и делает первые шаги? Для меня не составит труда перевод, для Вас не составит, а для него это китайская грамота. Через месяц или год и он без проблем будет читать подобный код. Но не сейчас. А помощь ему нужна именно сейчас.

Comment: Max ZS, я не вижу смысла спорить с тобой. Если нужна помощь, то приведен алгоритм, изучив который можно понять его работу и умножить свои знания. Если нужно решение задачи, то вот оно. Если у автора будут вопросы по разъяснению работы алгоритма - он их задаст.

Comment: Да и вообще, причем тут гуголь, когда на самом [SoEN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279278/finding-largest-prime-number-out-of-600851475143) [SoEN2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757763/integer-number-too-large-error-message-for-600851475143) есть аналогичные вопросы, с реализацией на Java, вероятнее можно найти и больше

Comment: Друзья мои, не стОит лишний раз доказывать тезис о том, что русский сегмент интернета по своей говнистости даст фору остальному миру.
В чем вообще причина вящего гнева некоторых личностей? Я вас чем-то обидел? Вы вообще не обязаны что-либо отвечать мне, а если уж хотите ответить, то давайте уж по сути. 

я делал поиск и нашел готовые ответы на яве, С, питоне и даже руби. 

да, с учетом градуса невменяемости русскоязычной тусовки буду как-то транслировать эти языки в Javascript, но до сих пор наивно полагал, что спросить будет проще...