# Как найти наибольший простой делитель?

Tags: алгоритм, простые-числа

Простые делители числа 13195 - это 5, 7, 13 и 29.

Каков самый большой делитель числа 600851475143, являющийся простым числом?

Необязательно писать ответ на определенном ЯП, просто непонятен алгоритм.

Comment: находим делитель https://younglinux.info/algorithm/euclidean дальше проверяем число на простоту. повторяем

Comment: и причем тут метка питона ?)

Comment: и еще https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505730/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-600851475143

Comment: @Viktorov это для того, чтобы знать на чем писать надо)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Разложить число на простые множители](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645227/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8). Раскладываете на множители и выбираете больший из них.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def simpleDividers(n):
   answer = []
   d = 2
   while d * d <= n:
       if n % d == 0:
           answer.append(d)
           n //= d
       else:
           d += 1
   if n > 1:
       answer.append(n)
   return answer

print(simpleDividers(13195))              # [5, 7, 13, 29]

print(simpleDividers(600851475143))       # [71, 839, 1471, 6857]

print(max(simpleDividers(600851475143)))  # 6857

print(simpleDividers(6857))               # [6857]
```

Comment: print(simpleDividers(600851475143)) Это выводит массив в котором одно число, равное исходному.

Answer (score 4):

```js
function maxPrimeDivider(n) {
  var res = n % 2 ? 1 : 2

  while (!(n % 2)) {
    n /= 2
  }

  for (var q=3; q*q<n; q+=2) {
    for (; !(n%q); n/=q) {
      res = q
    }
  }
  
  return res > n ? res : n
}

console.log([1, 2, 3, 7, 16, 17, 21, 617, 9*32*5*7, 13195].map(maxPrimeDivider).join(", "))

try {
  var maxPrimeDividerN = eval("(" + maxPrimeDivider.toString().replace(/\d+/g, "$&n") + ")")
  console.log(maxPrimeDividerN(BigInt(600851475143)) + "")
} catch (e) {
  console.error("BigInteger is not supported")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался в данной задаче и хочу показать свою получившуюся программу, и может понятно объяснить принцип ее работы (она достаточно эффективна - без массивов и списков, содержит только один вложенный цикл и пару условий). Язык - Java.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

                     //необходимые переменные
    int number = 10; //число, которое нужно проверить
    int i = number;  //переменная для первого цикла
    int j = 0;       //счетчик кол-ва делителей у делителя (i) числа number
    int k;           //переменная для второго цикла

                                     //начало цикла (основной)
    while (i > 0) {                  //первый цикл до тех пор, пока делитель (i) числа number будет > 0
        if (number % i == 0) {       //проверяем остаток от деления числа number на i (сам делитель)
            k = i;
                                     //начало цикла (второй)
            while (k > 0) {          //второй цикл, проверяем делители у i (i - делитель number)
                if (i % k == 0) {    //если i делится на k (k - делитель) без остатка,
                    j++;             //увеличиваем счетчик
                }
                k--;                 //подбираем следующее k
            }
            if (j == 2) {            //анализируем счетчик. Если кол-во делителей (k) у i = 2,
                                     //то число подходит => выводим его на экран
                System.out.print("Наибольший простой делитель числа " + number + ": " + i);
                break;               //т.к. мы искали число, постепенно уменьшая наибольший возможный
                                     //делитель, то первое попавшееся нам подходит, значит можно
                                     //сразу закончить работу программы
            }
            j = 0;                   //аннулирование счетчика. Если текущее значение нам не подошло,
                                     //значит нужен чистый счетчик для след. числа
        }
        i--;                         //подбираем следующее i, если текущее нам не подходит
    }                                //конец первого цикла
    }
}
```

И так. Так как нам нужно наибольший простой делитель, но пойдем сверху. И постепенно будет убавлять этот делитель на 1 до тех пор, пока не попадется нужный нам (это и есть первый цикл). Второй цикл вложен в первый и проверяет уже делители самого делителя числа (сложно, но здесь главное понять, дальше все легко).

Важной частью программы является счетчик (j). Он будет считать кол-во делителей у делителя числа. Если это число равно двум, значит оно является простым (а простое число делится только на 1 и на само себя) и оно нам подходит. Можно заканчивать программу и выводить число на экран.